# Prevent access to aspx files and allow access only via routing?

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-4.0

I have a url route which I declare at `global.asax` file :

```
  routes.MapPageRoute("RouteAdmin", "Admin/{Url}", "~/pages/MyPage.aspx", false);
```

But if the user tries to access  `mysite.com/pages/MyPage.aspx` he can still see the page

**Question :**

- Can I configure routing so  that *only routed* paths are acceptable ?

Comment: Check out this answer this may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532468/using-routeexistingfiles-to-block-access-to-existing-files-even-if-no-route-exis

Comment: @PandiyanCool I don't have any authentication mechanism. ( cuz my site doesn't require it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

If I access directly to the aspx file so I can check this prop:

`Page.RouteData.RouteHandler` is null

where

if I use route url it  is not null :

`{System.Web.Routing.PageRouteHandler}`

## Edit

(better solution)

Add those 2 lines to global asax

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("Route", "{*.}", "~/pages/default.aspx", false );
 routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Comment: So every time it will check this condition?

Comment: base page can do it easily. ( unless you have other solution).

Answer (score 1):

In `ASP.NET MVC` views are not accessible directly by defining them using a not found handler:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.aspx" />
    <add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```